# Spring Cloud Data Flow handling datasource errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a SpringBatch job implemented and trying to run it on Spring Cloud Data Flow.

When the properties are set properly, job runs smoothly.

But when the datasource properties are incorrect, the job will fail, but **without EXIT STATUS**. I am guessing it is because the job launcher has not yet started.

How should I properly handle this job and return a FAILED status to SCDF so that the flow continues ?

I am running a job with a jobLauncher in a custom Bean

```java
@Value("${jobName}")
String jobName;

@Bean
public JobExecution run(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
  JobExecution jobExecution = null;
  Job job;
  try {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
    job = BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(), Job.class, jobName);
    jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    log.info("Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
    return jobExecution;
}
```

It doesn't even get executed, because JPA datasource fails before it even has the chance.

How to properly handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is incorrect. You are creating a bean named `run` of type `JobExecution`. This means the batch job will be executed when Spring configures the application context. That's not the right time to start a batch job. A bean definition method should contain the bean definition, for example a job definition, but not execute it.

Database configuration should be independent from the job itself. If you have a bean of type `DataSource` that cannot be created due to incorrect properties, then the Spring application context will fail at that point before even loading/running the job.

Comment: In Spring Cloud Data Flow, the parent job is being executed first and then my Spring Batch Job tries to execute. When the DataSource in my JAR file fails to initialize, the application fails, but the SCDF Job will stay in UNKNOWN state, because Spring Batch Job did not even start. How to properly handle this case ?